# How to add a directory permanently to my Path?

Tags: paths

Basically I want to know that. How can I add a directory (/tmp in my case) to the Path permanently from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`export PATH=/tmp:$PATH` for your current session.

`echo -e '\nexport PATH=/tmp:$PATH' >> ~/.profile` for your future sessions.